# Why isn't my footer anchored to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I don't know why the footer div is not sticking to the bottom of my page? Ideally the content div should expand with the amount of actual content inside of it, and the footer should stay at the bottom, always. What am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.wrapper {
  width:960px;
  min-height: 570px;
  margin:0 auto;

}
.header{
  height:60px;
}
.nav {
  height:30px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-left:
  border-right:
}
.content {
  width:100%;

}
.mainContent{
  width:755px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-top: 0;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  border-top:0;
  border-left: 0;
  float:right;
}
.footer{
  height:100px;
  width:958px;
  border:1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(60,60,60);
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
li{
  display:inline-flex;
  padding:5px 40px 10px 40px;
}
input{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
label {
  height:15px;
  width:30px;
  color:red;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0)
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
input#Color {
  position:absolute;
}
input#Color:checked + .wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  -webkit-background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
input#Color:checked + * {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  -webkit-background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  color:red;
}
input#Color:checked + .wrapper .nav {
  -webkit-background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
input#Color:checked + .wrapper .content .mainContent {
  -webkit-background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top: 0;
  color:red;
}
input#Color:checked + .wrapper .footer {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  -webkit-background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  color:red;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- DOCKMANN INDEX PAGE - CODE: D001 -->
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS --><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<!-- JS --><script src="script.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <!-- END HEAD -->
<body>
  <label for="Color">Red Eye</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Color"/>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">

      test header
    </div>
    <!-- end header -->
    <div class="nav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              HOME
            </li>
            <li>
              ALBUM
            </li>
            <li>
              FILMS
            </li>
            <li>
              SOCIAL
            </li>
            <li>
              CONTACT
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end nav -->
    <div class="content">
          <div class="mainContent">
            mainContent
          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            Sidebar
          </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
    <div class="footer">
      test footer
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
 </div>
 <!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `.wrapper` is missing a `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give `position:fixed` to make that stay at the bottom of the page.Change your `position:absolute` of the footer to  `position:fixed` so it would be fixed to bottom always Or

```
.wrapper {
width:960px;
 min-height: 570px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}
```

so the footer will position relative to wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Code Below :::---

You have to specify it's state by using **top** or **margin-top** of CSS to position it.

```css
#foot{
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <footer class="container-fluid" id="foot">
  <span class="col-sm-3 text-center">
   HOME
  </span>
  <span class="col-sm-3 text-center">
   CONTACT
  </span>
  <span class="col-sm-3 text-center">
   FILMS
  </span>
  <span class="col-sm-3 text-center">
   ABOUT
  </span>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

of course if you want the footer to stay at the bottom when scrolling, you have to use position fixed  with the highest z-index